# How to create a count for Each entry in Postgres Database?

Tags: postgresql, timestamp, time-series-database

So I have my Table that looks some thing like

| Name | timestamp |
| --- | --- |
| abc | 2022-03-08 06:15:11 |
| bcd | 2022-03-08 08:15:11 |
| cvd | 2022-04-10 06:15:11 |

Now each Name is unique in this table and it has a timestamp associated with it.

I want to create a new table from this which will be something like a counter. So my updated table will look something like this.

| Name | timestamp |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-03-08 06:15:11 |
| 2 | 2022-03-08 08:15:11 |
| 3 | 2022-04-10 06:15:11 |

If anybody can help me how to achieve this that will be really great :)

Comment: You have to tell us how you want the rows sorted. The rows on a table don't have an order per se.